# Checking neighbour elements in flat array

Tags: arrays, bash, conways-game-of-life

Problem description: 
I want to iterate over an array (flattened 2D --> 1D array right now) and keep checking it's nearest neighbours. From that I want to determine if they are dead/alive ('X' or '.') and change their state accordingly to my rules(simplified conway's).

My grid looks like this e.g.:

```
...............
...........X...
.X.......X...X.
...............
....X..........
....X..........
...............
.....XX........
..........X....
...............
Cells alive: 9
```

But I have this array flattened to 1D array to iterate over it. So basically it turns to something like this: `....X...X....X.` etc.
After writing it down on a paper I think there are several cases to check in this "grid":

- TopLeft element (i = 0) - first element, 3 neighbours/cases to check
- TopRight element (i = nColumns - 1), as above
- BottomLeft element (i = nColumns * nRows - nColumns), as above
- BottomRight element (i = nColumns * nRows - 1) - last element, as above
- "Border" elements (5 neighbours each without corner elements)
- Middle elements with 8 neighbours

But it seems totally stupid to check it with some if's and case statements. If I could use real 2D arrays I think I could just create array of offset (-1, 1), (0, 1)... and so on. But I can't think of a way how to handle this with my code.
I will be very glad for any tips/examples and so on.

My code so far:

```
cellsAlive=0

#STDIN variables
geneFile=$1
nRows=$2 
nColumns=$3
let "cells = $nRows * $nColumns" 
declare -i tick_rate # instead maybe use watch or sleep

readarray -t geneArr < $geneFile # -t removes a trailing newline from each line read.
elementsCounts=${#geneArr[@]}

echo -e "--- Coordinates ---"
for (( i = 0; i < $elementsCounts; i++ )); do
    echo "${geneArr[$i]}" #| cut -d' ' -f2 $geneFile | head -2
done

echo -e "\n--- Grid ---"
#file must end with a newline
[[ $geneFile && -f $geneFile && -r $geneFile ]] || { printf >&2 'arg must be readable file.\n'; exit; }

array=()
for ((i=0; i<nRows*nColumns; ++i)); do
    array+=( '.' )
done
printf "\n"

while read -r x y; do 
    [[ $x && $y ]] || continue
    [[ $x = +([[:digit:]]) && $y = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || continue
    ((x=10#$x,y=10#$y)) #10 digit base
    (( x<nRows && y<nColumns )) || continue
    array[x+y*nRows]='X' 
    if [[ ${array[x+y*nRows]} == 'X' ]]; then
        let "cellsAlive += 1"
    fi
done < "$geneFile"

# print to stdout and to file
for((i=0;i<nColumns;++i)); do
    printf '%s' "${array[@]:i*nRows:nRows}" $'\n'
done | tee currentState 

arrayCopy=("${array[@]}")  
printf "Cells alive: %d" $cellsAlive ; printf "\n"

# printf "\n"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#arrayCopy[@]}; i++ )); do 
    #neighboursCount=0
    case $i in

        "0") if [[ ${arrayCopy[$(($i - 1))]} == 'X' ]] || [[ ${arrayCopy[$(($i + $nColumns))]} == 'X' ]] || [[ ${arrayCopy[$(($i + $nColumns + 1))]} == 'X' ]] ; then #TopLeft
            echo "That is just ridiculous way to check it..."
        fi ;;
        "$(($nColumns - 1))") printf "${arrayCopy[$i]}" ;; #TopRight
        "$(($nColumns*$nRows-1))") printf "${arrayCopy[$i]}" ;; #BottomRight
        "$(($nColumns*$nRows-$nColumns))") printf "${arrayCopy[$i]}" ;; #BottomLeft
        *) ;; #Middle elements with 8 neighbours
    esac
done
printf "\n"
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Example geneFile.txt (add blank like at the end):

```
1 2
4 5
6 7
13 2
5 7
4 4
9 2
11 1
10 8
```

Comment: sounds to me like you want to implement the as version for game of life :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting grid. Yeah well I'd be just happy for some kind of tip cause right now i'm going in circles and thinking about changing the way I approached the problem - but maybe thats not necessary and someone will give a good advice ^^. If the question is too general I can try to narrow it down to a specific problem (though I really need more of a general advice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. Here we go. Because i found this question interesting to be implemented in bash i just wrote an implementation of conway's game of life.

The main part to answer your question is probably: **how to access neighbours for a position in a matrix if it is linearized?**.

So you can access an element in a flatted matrix by

```
(row*fieldwidth)+columnoffset.
```

Every neighbour then can be accessed by adjusting `row` and `columnoffset` by `+/-1` starting with row and columnoffset at `0`.

Have a look at the `getnextstate` function to view the specialcases.

So here is the implementation. 
You are able to provide a file as input containing just `CELLALIVEMARKER`,`CELLDEADMARKER` and spaces. If the length for the flatted matrix does not fit the width/height parameter for the `FIELD` it just pads with random values.

```
#!/bin/bash

# system values
BASENAME="/usr/bin/basename"
ECHO="/bin/echo"
SLEEP="/bin/sleep"
TPUT="/usr/bin/tput"
GREP="/bin/grep"
WC="/usr/bin/wc"
CAT="/bin/cat"

if [ "${#}" != "4" -a "${#}" != "5" ]; then
  ${ECHO} "USAGE:    ./$(${BASENAME} ${0}) FIELDWIDTH FIELDHEIGHT RULESALIVE RULESDEAD [LINSTARTMATRIX]"
  ${ECHO} "EXAMPLES: ./$(${BASENAME} ${0}) 50         50          \"2 3\"    \"3\""
  ${ECHO} "          ./$(${BASENAME} ${0}) 50         50          \"2 3\"    \"3\""    init.mtx
  exit
fi

# field values
FWIDTH=${1}
FHEIGHT=${2}
# number of living neighbours for a living cell to stay alive in the next generation
RULESALIVE=($(${ECHO} ${3}))
# number of living neighbours for a dead cell to become alive in the next generation
RULESDEAD=($(${ECHO} ${4}))
CELLALIVEMARKER="o"
CELLDEADMARKER="."
FIELD=() # flatted matrix representation
# if there are just marker values or spaces in the file it is a valid one
${CAT} ${5} | ${GREP} -oq '[^\'${CELLALIVEMARKER}'\'${CELLDEADMARKER}'\ ]'
isvalid="${?}"
if [ "${5}" != "" ] && [ "${isvalid}" == "1" ]; then
  FIELD=($(${CAT} ${5}))
  # fill up with randoms if the length won't fit the dimension parameters
  if [ "${#FIELD[@]}" != "$((${FWIDTH}*${FHEIGHT}))" ]; then
    ${ECHO} "I: Padding matrix with random values."
    # fill up field with randoms if its too short
    for((i=${#FIELD[@]}; i<${FWIDTH}*${FHEIGHT}; i=$((${i}+1)))); do
      cell="${CELLALIVEMARKER}"
      alive=$((${RANDOM}%2))
      if [ "x${alive}" == "x1" ]; then
        cell="${CELLDEADMARKER}"
      fi
      FIELD[${#FIELD[@]}]="${cell}"
    done
  fi
else
  # fill random field
  for((i=0; i<${FWIDTH}*${FHEIGHT}; i=$((${i}+1)))); do
    cell="${CELLALIVEMARKER}"
    alive=$((${RANDOM}%2))
    if [ "x${alive}" == "x1" ]; then
      cell="${CELLDEADMARKER}"
    fi
    FIELD[${#FIELD[@]}]="${cell}"
  done
fi

# evaluate rules and get the next state for the cell
getnextstate() {
  local i="${1}" # row
  local j="${2}" # col
  local neighbours=""

  # left upper
  if [ "${i}" -eq "0" -a "${j}" -eq "0" ]; then
    neighbours="${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  # right upper
  elif [ "${i}" -eq "0" -a "${j}" -eq "$((${FWIDTH}-1))" ]; then
    neighbours="${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]}"
  # left bottom
  elif [ "${i}" -eq "$((${FHEIGHT}-1))" -a "${j}" -eq "0" ]; then
    neighbours="~${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  # right bottom
  elif [ "${i}" -eq "$((${FHEIGHT}-1))" -a "${j}" -eq "$((${FWIDTH}-1))" ]; then
  neighbours="?${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]}"
  # upper
  elif [ "${i}" -eq "0" -a "${j}" -gt "0" ]; then
    neighbours="-${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  # bottom
  elif [ "${i}" -eq "$((${FHEIGHT}-1))" -a "${j}" -gt "0" ]; then
    neighbours="=${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  # right
  elif [ "${i}" -gt "0" -a "${j}" -eq "0" ]; then
    neighbours="#${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  # left
  elif [ "${i}" -gt "0" -a "${j}" -eq "$((${FWIDTH}-1))" ]; then
    neighbours="_${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]}"
  # center
  else
    neighbours="@${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}-1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}-1)))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} ${FIELD[$((((${i}+1)*${FWIDTH})+(${j}+1)))]}"
  fi

  # count neighbours alive
  ncnt=$(${ECHO} ${neighbours} | ${GREP} -o ${CELLALIVEMARKER} | ${WC} -l)
  # evaluate rules
  local next=""
  if [ "${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]}" == "${CELLALIVEMARKER}" ] && [[ "$(${ECHO} ${RULESALIVE[@]})" =~ ${ncnt} ]]; then
    next="${CELLALIVEMARKER}"
  elif [ "${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]}" == "${CELLDEADMARKER}" ] && [[ "$(${ECHO} ${RULESDEAD[@]})" =~ ${ncnt} ]]; then
    next="${CELLALIVEMARKER}"
  else
    next="${CELLDEADMARKER}"
  fi
  ${ECHO} ${next}
}

firstrun=1
while [ true ]; do
  # print lines
  FIELD_UPDATE=()

  for((i=0; i<${FHEIGHT}; i=$((${i}+1)))); do
    line=""
    # calculate lines
    for((j=0; j<${FWIDTH}; j=$((${j}+1)))); do
      if [ "${firstrun}" == "1" ]; then
        line="${line}${FIELD[$(((${i}*${FWIDTH})+${j}))]} "
      # start calculation just after the first print
      elif [ "${firstrun}" == "0" ]; then
        line="${line}$(getnextstate ${i} ${j}) "
      fi
    done
    FIELD_UPDATE=($(${ECHO} ${FIELD_UPDATE[@]}) $(${ECHO} ${line}))
    ${ECHO} ${line}
  done
  FIELD=(${FIELD_UPDATE[@]})
  ${SLEEP} 2
  # refresh lines in the field
  for((i=0; i<${FHEIGHT}; i=$((${i}+1)))); do
    # refresh lines
    ${TPUT} cuu1
    ${TPUT} el
  done
  firstrun=0
done
```

So providing the file `init.mtx` containing the following matrix

```
. o . . . . . . . .
. . o . . . . . . .
o o o . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . .
```

you are able to create a simple glider (from the upper left to the bottom right)

```
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . o o 
. . . . . . . . o o
```

using Conway's default rules by running this script as follows:

```
./gameoflife 10 10 "2 3" "3" init.mtx
```

Hope this helps. 
And btw it was fun to implement this in bash :)

Comment: currently it is just a straight forwrd implementation. so if some one knows how to point out some performance values please let me know :)

Comment: Wow, I did not except duch comprehensive answer! Thanks a lot, glad It was fun for you:-).

Comment: No offense but your style is very bad. Please learn modern Bash techniques—you know, so that we don't spam the internet with antique and broken shell techniques for future generations to dig. May I point you to the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thank you for the guides but what exactly do i have to look for? accessing array elements (btw someone told me it is outdated but it is kind of intuitive)? so what else? just let me know so i can look further.

Comment: 1. Use of uppercase variable names is considered very bad practice. 2. You shouldn't use the full path of the commands and store these in a variable to execute them. Besides, you're here using the _external_ command `echo` instead of the builtin, which is very bad. 3. You're using too many external commands (and useless uses of `cat`s) for stuff that Bash can handle more efficiently on its own. 4. The way you split your strings is broken: it's subject to pathname expansion (and isn't really semantically correct).

Comment: 5. `while [ true ]` is indeed an infinite loop, but you show that you don't really know what's going on here. `while true` is much better. 6. Honestly there are too many uppercase letters, it's too ugly to read (see point 1). 7. Probably many more problems, but I can't see them, it's too unreadable.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks a lot. i will keep things in mind when writing sth else.